# Array distribution with changing number of values

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, distribution

I have an array of users in which I need to provide products, for example:

The number of values is always changing - the first time the distribution is carried out there might only be one value, the second time three.

These values must be shuffled and distributed whilst ensuring that an individual does not get the same value twice.

What I have managed to do so far shuffles the array and gives each user ten products:

```
var users = ["user1", "user2", "user3"];

var products = ["p1", "p2", "p3", "p4", "p5", "p6", "p7", "p8", "p9", "p10","p11", "p12", "p13", "p14", "p15", "p16", "p17", "p18", "p19", "p20", "p21", "p22", "p23", "p24", "p25", "p26", "p27", "p28", "p29", "p30"];

function shuffle(array) {
var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

while (0 != currentIndex) {

  randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
  currentIndex -= 1;

  temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
  array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
  array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
}

return array;
}

i = 0;
while (i < users.length) { 
    newArray = (shuffle(products)).slice(0, 10)
    console.log(users[i++] + ' products: ' + newArray);
}
```

Result:

```
user1 products: p5,p6,p13,p2,p19,p22,p8,p20,p27,p28
user2 products: p6,p30,p22,p9,p25,p2,p7,p17,p19,p10
user3 products: p20,p25,p23,p4,p28,p9,p12,p14,p21,p17
```

Comment: What did you have in mind in terms of distributing the values? Does each person get all values, or do you just want to distribute values across people as evenly as possible without duplicates?

Comment: Hi Mike, no not every person should get all values - the values need to be distributed across all, however it's ok for some people to have some values the same just in a different order and without the same value twice.

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Is its output not like you desire?

Comment: @trincot no as not every product is distributed

Comment: @trincot and currently I have set it to distribute 10 products whereas if there were only one product avaliable it must give it to one random user

Comment: Is there a minimum or maximum to the number of products a single user can get? If there is one product, is there any reason why not every user could get that same product? You seemed to suggest earlier that 2 users may receive the same product...

Comment: @trincot It would depend on the ratio of products to users, ideally if there were three users and thirty products for example each user would receive a shuffled array of ten products with low match rate of products with others. Whereas if there were five users and one product, this product could be distributed to two users.

Comment: If there are 30 products and 3 users, and each user gets 10 products *and all products must be assigned*, then there is no possibility for any product to be shared. So how do you see that *low match rate*?

Comment: @trincot 2 in 10 would be ideal

Comment: Not possible with 30 products and 3 users according to the rule that all products must be distributed. If you would say each of the 3 users should get 12, then it is possible.

Comment: @trincot All products must be distributed but two users may have more products than the third - as once another product is added to the array this would be distributed to the remaining user

Comment: I understand that. It is just not possible if you have 30 products, 3 users, and want each user to get 10 products, of which 2 should be shared with others, while still distributing all products. Just do the math.

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty in this problem is that you want to distribute a bit more than there are products, so that a few products are attributed to more than one user. Yet you also want to distribute the products about evenly and ensure that no-one gets a duplicate product.

To do this efficiently, i.e. in linear time in terms of users and products, some more code will be needed.

This is what the following algorithm will stick to:

- All products will be distributed at least once;
- About 20% of them (rounded upwards) will be distributed a second time;
- No user will get the same product twice;
- All users will receive almost the same number of products. The difference is at the most one product;
- The users that might have one product less are randomly chosen;
- The order of the products that a user receives is random.

```js
function shuffled(arr) {
  // Does NOT alter the given array, but returns new one
  arr = arr.slice();
  var i = arr.length;
  while (i) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i--);
    [ arr[i], arr[j] ] = [ arr[j], arr[i] ];
  }
  return arr;
};

function distribute(products, users) {
    // Cases with only one possible outcome:
    if (users.length === 0) return {};
    if (users.length === 1) return { [users[0]]: shuffled(products) };    

    // We will distribute about 20% of the products twice
    var distributeCount = Math.ceil(products.length * 1.2); 
    
    // Create object structure to return: key is user name, 
    //   value is set of products
    var possessions = users.reduce( (acc, user) => 
        Object.assign(acc, { [user]: new Set() }), {} );

    // Order of users in which products will be assigned
    var usersLeft = shuffled(users);
    while (usersLeft.length < distributeCount)
        usersLeft = usersLeft.concat(usersLeft);
    usersLeft.length = distributeCount; // clip array to exact size
    
    // Order of products in which they will be assigned; double length
    var productsLeft = shuffled(products).concat(shuffled(products)); 

    // Assign products to users
    while (usersLeft.length) {
        product = productsLeft.pop();
        user = usersLeft.pop();
        if (possessions[user].has(product)) { // not allowed to add again
            if (usersLeft.length) { // not the very last product distribution
                // swap with next user, as others do not have this product
                [ user, usersLeft[usersLeft.length-1] ] = 
                    [ usersLeft[usersLeft.length-1], user ]; 
            } else {
                // The very last product distribution:
                // pick another product: this will eventually work, as 80% 
                // of the products are available, 
                // and a user only has at most 50% of them.
                do {
                    product = productsLeft.pop();
                    if (!product) throw "Could not find product for user";
                } while (possessions[user].has(product));
            }
        }
        possessions[user].add(product);
    }
    // Turn Sets into Arrays
    for (user in possessions) possessions[user] = [...possessions[user]];
    return possessions;
}

var users = ["user1", "user2", "user3"];
var products = ["p1", "p2", "p3", "p4", "p5", "p6", "p7", "p8", "p9", "p10","p11", 
                "p12", "p13", "p14", "p15", "p16", "p17", "p18", "p19", "p20", "p21", 
                "p22", "p23", "p24", "p25", "p26", "p27", "p28", "p29", "p30"];

var result = distribute(products, users);

console.log(result);
```